# Scroll function of MSI Laptop's touchpad is not working on Ubuntu (but on Windows)

Tags: 20.04, touchpad

I just moved from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my MSI GE70 2QE Apache Pro laptop.

My touchpad is working fine, but in Windows 10 my touchpad had this function that allows me to go down or up in (websites,file explorer, etc.) just by moving my finger on the right side of it. In Ubuntu this function is not working.

How can I enable this functionality on Ubuntu?

Comment: Details as to what hardware you're using (no the box which you provided, but what hardware is found inside your box); the following maybe helpful in getting details of what's inside your msi ge70 box.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection   ... note: Sorry i'm no expert in touchpads (*I disable them where I can*) so you'll get better advice from others I'd hope if you wait.

Comment: dont worry and thx for your time, also you kinda  solve it for me with  the link you share. my problem was the thid point  and i solve it following the guide

Comment: @JcAm It's great to see that you managed to solve your problem! Can you please add an answer with the procedure you followed to solve it, so that other people with the same problem can solve it too? If you add it, please ping me (adding `@BeastOfCaerbannog` in your comment) and I will gladly upvote your answer. Thanks!